# Sleep mode prevents Shutdown -h. Is there a workaround?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, suspend, shutdown

I like using `shutdown -h`. It lets me leave my computer knowing that it'll turn off. However, if I leave it for so long that sleep mode kicks in, the scheduled shutdown gets ignored. Is there any way to make `shutdown -h`'s shutdown trigger during sleep?

Comment: The machine is sleeping how can it run a command?

Comment: just disable the sleep mode